# NameError: free variable 'ar' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, session-variables

I use tf.while_loop in simple code using tensorflow. It gives me this error

> ar = tf.cond(tf.less(arg[i], 1), lambda: tf.concat([ar,[1.0]], axis = 0), lambda: tf.concat([ar,[0.0]], axis = 0))
>
> NameError: free variable 'ar' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

the code::

```
a = tf.constant([[[1,2],[4,3]],[[5,6],[8,7]]])

arg = tf.argmax(a, axis =2)

arg = tf.cast(tf.reshape(arg,[4]), tf.int32)



i =tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i,4)

def body(i):

    ar = tf.cond(tf.less(arg[i], 1), lambda: tf.concat([ar,[1.0]], axis = 0), lambda: tf.concat([ar,[0.0]], axis = 0))

    print(i)

    i = tf.add(i,1)

    return i

ar = tf.constant([1])

r = tf.while_loop(c,body,[i])

sess =tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

sess.run(r)

print(sess.run(ar))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
global ar
```

line above

```
ar = tf.cond(tf.less(arg[i], 1), lambda: tf.concat([ar,[1.0]], axis = 0), lambda: tf.concat([ar,[0.0]], axis = 0))
```

in the `body` function